# My php code for identifying location of users with GeoLite City database is only partly working. Can someone take a look?

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, maxmind

I have simple php code to show ads in certain geo locations (US regions) and it works for some states but not for others. Can anyone take a look at my code & spot errors?

This code below is what I'm using to try to get US state location from visitors and show them particular ads if they are from those states. This is on an nginx server and the host already set up separate buckets for the cache so that certain US states (the ones identified below) would have different caches. I have cleared the server cache. The midwestern location works (Tennessee & Kentucky) but the east coast location does not work (DC). Can anyone give any tips on my php? I would so appreciate it. The database is MaxMind GeoLite City database & therefore the regions/US states data should be available.

The Wordpress framework is [beans](https://www.getbeans.io/) and uses the "beans smart action."

```
<?php    
beans_add_smart_action('beans_content_prepend_markup', 'top_geo_home_ad', 5);

function top_geo_home_ad() {
$jg_user_location = getenv('GEOIP_REGION_NAME');
$jg_event_locations = array('Massachusetts', 'District of Columbia', 'Tennessee', 'Kentucky', 'New York', 'Maryland', 'DC',  'Delaware', 'Pennsylvania', 'Virginia');
if ($jg_user_location == 'District of Columbia' || $jg_user_location == 'New York' || $jg_user_location == 'Maryland' || $jg_user_location == 'Massachusetts' || $jg_user_location == 'Delaware' || $jg_user_location == 'Pennsylvania' || $jg_user_location == 'Virginia') {
    $jg_user_location = 'DC'; 
} elseif ($jg_user_location == 'Kentucky') { 
    $jg_user_location = 'Tennessee';
}
if(in_array( $jg_user_location, $jg_event_locations, TRUE )!==FALSE) {
    beans_add_smart_action( 'beans_content_prepend_markup', 'CEO_geoad_' . $jg_user_location, 6 );
    }
else {
    beans_add_smart_action( 'beans_content_prepend_markup', 'jg_normal_top_ad', 6);
}
}


function CEO_geoad_DC() {
    echo '<div class="ad-wrap horiz">' . do_shortcode('[aas_zone zone_id="56461"]') . '</div>';
}

function CEO_geoad_Tennessee() {
    echo '<div class="ad-wrap horiz">' . do_shortcode('[aas_zone zone_id="56470"]') . '</div>';
}

function jg_normal_top_ad() {
    echo '<div class="ad-wrap horiz">' . do_shortcode('[aas_zone zone_id="49497"]') . '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing...

```
if(in_array( $jg_user_location, $jg_event_locations, TRUE )!==FALSE) {...
```

to this (remove extra equal sign)...

```
if(in_array( $jg_user_location, $jg_event_locations, TRUE )!=FALSE) {...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it.

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please accept my answer as your solution? Let me know if you run into other issues. Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: Got it. Didn't realize I had to do that. Thanks again.